# Checking if a file exists then do something if it's not a directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-system

While I'm aware that code with callbacks tends to be complex, I'm wondering if there are any patterns or something to improve my situation.

All I do here is check if a file exists and then print its name if it's not a directory:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    filename = process.args[2];

fs.exists(filename, function(exists) {
  if (exists) {
    fs.stat(filename, function(err, stats) { 
      if (stats.isDirectory()) {
        console.log(filename + ": is a directory");
      } else {
        // do something with file
        console.log(filename);
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log(filename + ": no such file");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can actually omit `fs.exists()`. The `fs.stat()` will return an error when the item you are testing is not there. You can scavenge through the `err` object that `fs.stat()` returns to see what error caused it. As I remember, when `fs.stat()` stats a non-existing entry, it returns an `ENOENT, no such file or directory` error.

And so:

```
var fs = require('fs')
  , filename = process.args[2]
  ;

fs.stat(filename, function(err, stats) { 
  if(err){
    //doing what I call "early return" pattern or basically "blacklisting"
    //we stop errors at this block and prevent further execution of code

    //in here, do something like check what error was returned
    switch(err.code){
      case 'ENOENT':
        console.log(filename + ' does not exist');
        break;
      ...
    }
    //of course you should not proceed so you should return
    return;
  }

  //back there, we handled the error and blocked execution
  //beyond this line, we assume there's no error and proceed

  if (stats.isDirectory()) {
    console.log(filename + ": is a directory");
  } else {
    console.log(filename);
  }
});
```

So essentially, we reduced the number of indents caused by callbacks and also reduced it by restructuring `if-else` statements